# jquery after/insertAfter - unable to insert a new element

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

It's something very obvious but I am not able to see it despite looking at very similar issues other people have faced and gotten solved in stackoverflow. I'm hoping it jumps out at you. Please help me figure out why I am not able to insert (or insertAfter) an existing element.

I've included my html view file (I'm using codeigniter) with the relevant javascript.

As ever, thanks very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Afterview</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="divm@n.com">
            <li>
                Click for more details.&nbsp;
                <a id="m@n.com" class="detailbtn" href="#detail-id">(Details)</a>
            </li>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var html_string;
    $('.detailbtn').each(function(i){
        $(this).click(function(){
            html_string='<li>hello</li>';
            $('.divm@n.com').insertAfter(html_string).show();
       });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change your code to use `.after()` and fix your class name like this:

```
$('.divmncom').after('<li>hello</li>').show();
```

Change your class name to `<div class="divmncom">` to get rid of special characters that are being interpreted differently than you want.

And, while you're cleaning things up, you should get rid of the `html_string` global variable, by either removing the need for it entirely or making it a local variable.

---

By way of explanation, it appears that you don't understand how `insertAfter()` works.  When you have:

```
$(x).insertAfter(y)
```

it inserts each element that matches the selector `x` after the target represented by `y`.  In your code:

```
 html_string='<li>hello</li>';
 $('.divm@n.com').insertAfter(html_string).show();
```

`html_string` does match any existing DOM elements so it doesn't have a place to do the insertion.

Further, the CSS selector `.divm@n.com'` may have problems with the `@` character and will interpret the `.` in `.com` as the start of a second class which is not what you want.  There are probably ways to escape those special characters and still use them, but it's much safer code to just stop using them entirely and make your class names be simple class names that don't need special characters escaped.

You should probably read the pages for the two related jQuery methods [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to make sure you apply the right parameters to the right method for your particular problem.    It looks to me like you want to be using `.after()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

i dont understand the code but you need to escape the period and `@` in the selector

```
$('.divm\\@n\\.com')
```

edit

from the look of it you can replace

```
$('.detailbtn').each(function(i){           
        $(this).click(function(){
            html_string='<li>hello</li>';
            $('.divm@n.com').insertAfter(html_string).show();
       });
    });
```

with

```
$(".detailbtn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 $("<li>hello</li>").insertAfter(".divm\\@n\\.com");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/68TwD/)

P.S. also see @jfriend00 answer for how `insertAfter` works

Comment: THanks for your explanation.I'll read up a bit more on this as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need 2 escape variables, one for the `@` and one for the `.`.

For what I understand, it appears that you want to append some `HTML` code after the link is clicked, if that's so, I recommend using `append()` (you can also use `after()` if you want)

**HTML**

```
<div class="divm@n.com">
<li>
    Click for more details.&nbsp;
    <a id="m@n.com" class="detailbtn" href="#detail-id">(Details)</a>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
$('.detailbtn').click(function(){
    var html_string='<li>hello</li>';
    $('.divm\\@n\\.com').after(html_string);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/dTkPf/5/) is a working solution...

Comment: Thanks very much! I will look into this approach - thanks especially for the working soln! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The class-name "divm@n.com" is invalid, because it contains an '.', which means, that the element should have a class "divm@n" and a class "com".
And to insert the value from html_string after this element, you have to use the .after() function or change your current .insertAfter() to this:

```
$(html_string).insertAfter('.divm@ncom').show();
```

This is, what i got:

```
var html_string;
$('.detailbtn').each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
        html_string='<li>hello</li>';
        $('.divm@ncom').after(html_string).show();
   });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I need to rethink some of my logic that currently needs the .com part. Thanks again.